Multithreads of fftw on 2D matrix's transform
I wonder the principle of multithreading fftw on 2D matrix, if fftw uses multithreads to transform every row of the matrix.If not, i want to use multithreads to conduct 1D fft on the rows of matrix in parallel to accelerate the transform.
I have try many fft libraries, and fftw should be the most known and stable one to conduct fft on 2D matrix.However, I want to know if the fftw's multithreads in its document has accomplish the parallel transform on every row of the matrix.

Depending on the dimensions of the matrix and sizes of the different levels of cache the whole system goes memory bandwidth limited on 2D FFT transforms pretty quickly so that there is no advantage at all to multithreading beyond some rather modest number of cores. It is worth doing the experiment to see  where the optimum is on your system is for a given problem if you will be doing lots of them all the same size. Beyond that point you merely generate a more heat to get the answer more slowly. The gains from using real image to complex conjugate symmetric transform are more important.

@Martin Brown Thank you for your answer,  I have used the rfft and that does make sense. However, if fftw does not conduct parallel transform on every row of  the 2D matrix, i want to try realise that and see the result in effecient.

Just try it first with 2 threads and then 3 or 4 threads. I'd be very surprised if there was any worthwhile speed increase  going beyond that number of threads. Cache locality is essential to making a 2D FFT run quickly.
